# Sign in with google in my website

Tags: single-sign-on, google-signin

I have created Client Id in google console, and I put the code given in google console,
but if I have already signed in gmail in other tab, and I open my website it automatically sign in with gmail.

I want to know that how can I implement this so that when user press 'Sign in with google' then only it goes to other page.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having that issue. I think if we use a javascript onclick function, that should work. But have you got any solutions yet?